# How to use ORACLE DECODE() in MSSQL server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, date, decode

how to migrate the below query into mssql server im suffering a lot in this migration.. help will be appreciated..

```
select FEES,
DECODE(SUBCOM_TYPE ,'S','SPECIAL COMMISSION','D','DEFAULT COMMISSION') AS SUBCOM_TYPE,
TO_CHAR(FROMDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS FROMDATE, 
TO_CHAR(TODATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TODATE,
TO_CHAR(ADDEDDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS ADDEDDATE,
USER_CODE from COMMISSION 
where INST_ID = 'ABC' AND MASTERCODE='106'
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE` function

```
Select .....
CASE SUBCOM_TYPE
WHEN 'S' THEN 'SPECIAL COMMISION'
WHEN 'D' THEN 'DEFAULT COMMISION'
END
```